# How to configure nginx as proxy to a dotnet server via https

Tags: .net, docker, nginx, .net-core, docker-compose

There is an app that is .net core app, I don't have access to source code but I have a compiled version that should work only via https.

I have nginx config that uses https and proxy to running dotnet app.

```
worker_processes 4;
events { worker_connections 1024; }
http {
   sendfile on;
   upstream app_servers {
   server dotnetapp:5000;
}
server {
    listen 8080 ssl default_server;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;
    location / {
            proxy_pass         http://app_servers;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

}

and it works ok along with dotnet app without docker running
`dotnet dotnetapp.dll`

But when we trying to connect docker here we got

`The current request was rejected because the OpenID Connect server middleware has been configured to reject HTTP requests. To permanently disable the transport security requirement, set 'OpenIdConnectServerOptions.AllowInsecureHttp' to 'true'.`

Dockerfile for dotnet app

`FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0-runtime
WORKDIR /var/www
EXPOSE 5000/tcp
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS="http://*:5000";
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "dotnetapp.dll"]`

Dockerfile for nginx

`FROM nginx
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install iputils-ping curl -y
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

docker-compose.yml

`version: '3'
services:
  dotnetapp:
    build: docker
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '5000:5000'
    volumes:
      - ./dotnetapp:/var/www

  nginx:
    build: docker-nginx
    restart: always
    volumes:
        - ~/Documents/ssl:/etc/nginx/ssl
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    depends_on:
      - dotnetapp`